# Auto detect json result type to have intellisense

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax

Let's say you have a controller which returns a `JsonResult` object.

It can return result A:

```
return Json(new { succeeded = false, message = "Message goes here." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

result B:

```cs
return Json(new { succeeded = true, message = "Message goes here.", names = listOfNames }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

or result C:

```cs
return Json(new { succeeded = true, message = "Message goes here.", names = listOfNames, moreProps }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Or even return result D, E, F, etc...

Let's say I know I get a return of type A. In my ajax success function I have no intellisense and this is very error sensitive:

```js
success: function (result) {
    var var1NoIntellisence = result.succeeded;//No intellisense
    var var2NoIntellisence = result.errorMessage;//No intellisense
```

I made this javascript 'class'.

```js
function ResultA(r) {
    this.succeeded = r.succeeded;
    this.message = r.message;
}
```

Now, if I do this I have intellisense:

```js
success: function (result) {
    var var1NoIntellisence = result.succeeded;//No intellisense
    var var2NoIntellisence = result.message;//No intellisense
    var resultObject = new Result(result);
    var var1WithIntellisense = resultObject.succeeded;//Intellisense available!!
    var var2WithIntellisense = resultObject.message;//Intellisense available!!
}
```

Is there a way/method/lib you can auto-detect the result type to have intellisense available and not explicitly have to cast it first? (Not having to cast also means not having to have javascript return classes) I already did some research, but I am afraid the answer is no...